# Why does git not respect my .gitignore file on windows?

Tags: git

I'm trying to setup a .gitignore file with the following rule

```
*/bin
```

but it is not ignoring all `bin` folders unless I use a backslash

```
*\bin
```

Shouldn't it work the same across all platforms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need to specify the * at the beginning. The following example will ignore any bin or Bin directory in any part of the directory tree.

```
[Bb]in/
```

The previous example is for visual studio, as it creates the bin folder in lower or upper case. You can see an example of a .gitignore that I've used in windows [here](https://github.com/augusto/silverlight-in-action/blob/master/.gitignore).

I forgot to add that if you're going to use git on windows, you might want to set to ignore case in the configuration file in .git/config by adding

```
[core]
{...}
    ignorecase = true
{...}
```

Comment: A little explanation: `*` (as in `*/bin`) doesn't match slashes. It can only match within one path component. Additionally, the presence of a `/` means that the pattern is only checked from the level of the gitignore. So `*/bin` only ignores files/directories called bin that are one level down.